# Create one associative array from another in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to implement a rudimentary module-like import in Shell.

My idea is that the importable modules should have an `EXPORTS` associative array, and the `import` function takes the variable name to assign to and the module filename (e.g. `import MYMODULE module.sh`)

Here is my main file (being sourced into a Bash session)

```shell
#!/bin/bash

import () {
    eval "declare -A $1"
    {
        source "$2"
        for i in "${!EXPORTS[@]}"
        do
            echo "from import (line 9): ${1}[$i]=${EXPORTS[$i]}"
            eval "${1}[$i]=${EXPORTS[$i]}"
        done
    }
}

import VAR echo.sh

for i in ${!VAR[@]}
do
    echo "from module (line 19): VAR[$i]=${VAR[$i]}"
done
```

And here is `echo.sh`

```shell
declare -A EXPORTS
EXPORTS[foo]="bar"
EXPORTS[baz]="ree"
```

Here is my current output

```
$ source module.sh
from import (line 9): VAR[baz]=ree
from import (line 9): VAR[foo]=bar

# expected output also includes
# > from module (line 19): VAR[baz]=ree
# > from module (line 19): VAR[foo]=bar
```

Basically I wanted a local VAR variable to have been created (it hasn't). It works if I'm not trying to do it with an array.

What am I doing wrong (besides "this is a bad idea" -- I'm doing it for learning purposes).

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Sorry! Removed it accidentally in an edit. It's in the question now

Comment: Why not create output `declare -A VAR=( [baz]=ree [foo]=bar )`, all in one line? You can get most of the way there with `declare -p VAR`, and not need to generate the key/value pairs yourself.

Comment: BTW, note that your current code has serious security bugs. When using `eval`, you don't want to expand values -- doing so would make a variable containing `$(touch /tmp/foo)` as a value *run that code*. Always, always use `printf %q` to escape content when doing code generation in bash, if you *must* do it at all -- in this case, that means the command to generate your string to eval might be something like `printf -v eval_str '%q[%q]=%q\n' "$1" "$i" "${EXPORTS[$i]}"` to populate the variable `eval_str`.

Comment: Would my code work with that change? Think Node or Python modules. Of course there would be a bit less flexibility, but that's about the effect I'm trying to achieve.

If you provide this as an answer and it works I'll gladly accept it, thanks for your time so far =)

Comment: Actually that is why I need to eval, because the variable names here could be anything.

Comment: the problem you encounter is because `declare` inside a function is like `local`

Comment: Is there a way to use assoc arrays without resorting to `declare` or `typeset`?